# Protobuf : pass protobuf message from Javascript to C++ WebAssembly module

Tags: javascript, c++, protocol-buffers, protobuf-c, protobuf.js

I would like to pass a protobuf message from Javascript to a C++ WebAssembly module.

I do receive, and can successfully parse the simpler protobuf messages on the C++ side, however, protobuf is failing to parse the less-simple protobuf messages.

Here is the code that I am using :

```js
goog.module('protobufMessageGenerator');
goog.require('proto.my_proto.MyMessage');

function generateMyMessage() {
    var msg = new proto.my_proto.MyMessage()
    var internal = new proto.my_proto.MyMessageInternal()
    internal.setAccentColor("#CC1D24")
    internal.setLogo("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")
    msg.setInternal(internal)
    return msg
}
```

Using the google-closure-compiler, I compile this protobuf message generator to pure Javascript.
I use this code to pass the message to the C++ WebAssembly module :

```js
function sendMessage() {
    Module.self().setMyMessage(module$contents$protobufMessageGenerator_generateMyMessage().serializeBinary())
}
sendMessage()
```

I receive the message on the C++ side using this code :

```cpp
void JavascriptPublicInterface::setMyMessage(const QString &myMessage)
{
    if (_myMessage != myMessage)
    {
        _myMessage = myMessage;
        emit myMessageChanged();
    }
}

void JavascriptPublicInterface::setMyMessageEMS(const std::string &myMessage)
{
    setMyMessage(QString::fromStdString(myMessage));
}

//...

void startListeningToMyMessage(std::function<void(euf_proto::MyMessage myMessage)> listener)
{
    const auto changedListener = [listener]() {
        const auto newMyMessageString = JavascriptPublicInterface::self()->myMessage();
        my_proto::MyMessage myMessagePb;
        if (myMessagePb.ParseFromString(newMyMessageString.toStdString()))
        {
            qDebug() << "C++ : Successfully parsed new MyMessage: " << newMyMessageString;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "C++ : Failed to parse new MyMessage: " << newMyMessageString;
        }

        qDebug() << "MyMessage received: " << QString::fromStdString(myMessagePb.DebugString());

        listener(myMessagePb);
    };
    if (!QObject::connect(JavascriptPublicInterface::self(), &JavascriptPublicInterface::myMessageChanged, changedListener))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to connect to JavascriptPublicInterface myMessageChanged");
    }
}
```

In the Javascript console I see : "C++ : Failed to parse new MyMessage: ..."

I guess that it can be related to the fact that Javascript is using UTF-16 and C++ is using UTF-8 encoding (because the messages that are UTF-8 only can be successfully parsed), so I tried to fix the sending and receiving like this:

```js
//For more info see : https://emscripten.org/docs/api_reference/emscripten.h.html?highlight=stringtoutf8
function convertUtf16ToUtf8(input) {
    var uint8Arr = input
    var jsString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, uint8Arr)
    var lengthBytes = lengthBytesUTF8(jsString)+1
    var stringOnWasmHeap = _malloc(lengthBytes)
    stringToUTF8(jsString, stringOnWasmHeap, lengthBytes)
    return stringOnWasmHeap
}

function sendMessage() {
var myMessage = convertUtf16ToUtf8(module$contents$protobufMessageGenerator_generateMyMessage().serializeBinary())
    Module.self().setMyMessage(myMessage)
    _free(myMessage)
}
sendMessage()
```

And I modified the parsing on the C++ side like this :

```cpp
void JavascriptPublicInterface::setMyMessageEMS(const int pointer)
{
    const char* msg = (char*)pointer;
    setMyMessage(QString::fromStdString(msg));
}
```

But I still get this error : "C++ : Failed to parse new MyMessage: ..."

How could I fix this?

(I am using protobuf 3.19.1 (same version on both the Javascript and the C++ side).)

**UPDATE** :
In case if I modify my code, so it is passing a simple string as logo, then I can successfully parse the protobuf message on the C++ side :

```
internal.setLogo("logo")
```

So I guess that the issue is with this field.
The original string is a base64 encoded image.
What should I do with this string to fix the parsing?

Comment: Probably off-topic: When i considered protobuf as wasm (api-)serialization tool for a prototype in the past, the fact, that it needs a non-trivial runtime-library (protobuf), which imho would be needed to be compiled with emsscripten too, made this quite non-appealing. I then used flatbuffers in my prototype as those are header-only. Did you prepare the runtime-lib in any compatible way?

Comment: @sascha : I don't know if this answers your question, or not, but I did compile protobuf for WebAssembly. (As I mentioned, parsing UTF-8 only protobuf messages does work.)

Comment: Check the length of the received message, maybe it is getting truncated to some buffer length.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.

This stackoverflow post described a really similar issue, and it helped me to fix my parsing as well :
[Protobuf: Serialize/DeSerialize C++ to Js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68750875/protobuf-serialize-deserialize-c-to-js)

Here is my updated code, which works well :
I had to update the Javascript side :

```js
function sendMessage() {
    Module.self().setMyMessage(module$contents$protobufMessageGenerator_generateMyMessage().serializeBinary().toString())
}
sendMessage()
```

and the C++ side :

```cpp
namespace
{
QByteArray decryptProtobufMessage(const std::string &str)
{
    QStringList strList = QString::fromStdString(str).split(',');
    QByteArray bytedata;
    foreach (const QString &str, strList)
    {
        bytedata += (str.toUInt());
    }
    return bytedata;
}
} // namespace

void JavascriptPublicInterface::setMyMessage(const QByteArray &myMessage)
{
    if (_myMessage != myMessage)
    {
        _myMessage = myMessage;
        emit myMessageChanged();
    }
}

void JavascriptPublicInterface::setMyMessageEMS(const std::string &myMessage)
{
    setMyMessage(decryptProtobufMessage(myMessage));
}

//...

void startListeningToMyMessage(std::function<void(euf_proto::MyMessage myMessage)> listener)
{
    const auto changedListener = [listener]() {
        const auto newMyMessageByteArray = JavascriptPublicInterface::self()->myMessage();
        my_proto::MyMessage myMessagePb;
        if (myMessagePb.ParseFromArray(newMyMessageByteArray.data(), newMyMessageByteArray.size()))
        {
            qDebug() << "C++ : Successfully parsed new MyMessage: " << newMyMessageByteArray;
        }
        else
        {
            qDebug() << "C++ : Failed to parse new MyMessage: " << newMyMessageByteArray;
        }

        qDebug() << "MyMessage received: " << QString::fromStdString(myMessagePb.DebugString());

        listener(myMessagePb);
    };
    if (!QObject::connect(JavascriptPublicInterface::self(), &JavascriptPublicInterface::myMessageChanged, changedListener))
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to connect to JavascriptPublicInterface myMessageChanged");
    }
}
```